# Extra space using coordinator layout while scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-coordinatorlayout

In my app Am using CoordinatorLayout.When am trying to scroll lot of extra space is available.And i have changed that by using setting coordinator layout height.But when am trying to change the tab which is showing extra space.When am clicking in the form tab1,tab2,tab3 there is no issue.But when am trying to do with tab3,tab2,tab1 in tab3 and tab2 showing lot of extra space.

```
1) In my main activity am using Observable scrollview.

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/kudix_cordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/parallax_image_height"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/kudix_club_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Each tab fragment contain different types of UI.

Comment: What do you really mean by extra space? Can you provide a screenshot!

Comment: at bottom there is lot of space

Comment: There'll normally be a space if you have no content to fill it with! Is'nt that normal!

Comment: not normal space actually what ever my list item height that is taking for other tab layout too

Comment: i have fixed the issue..Actually it was taking my list view height  from the other layout.The progress dialog was not dismissing so the API keep on calling .And in that API i was setting coordinator layout height.For each tab am setting coordinator layout height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it was taking my list view height from the other layout.The progress dialog was not dismissing so the API keep on calling .And in that API i was setting coordinator layout height.For each tab am setting coordinator layout height.